# CSS: Call hover of other object on hover

Tags: css, xml, hover

I'm currently working on a xml+css project. I have a xml with class: player class="center" id ="z01" menID="m_John_Smith">

I'm looking for a way to call hover on all players whose id is m_John_Smith whenever I use hover of John_Smith object.

Any ideas?

Comment: `call hover on all players whose id is m_John_Smith` first of all do not use duplicate id's on one page. Second, is there a DOM relationship between the `John_Smith` and `m_John_Smith` ?

Answer (score 1):

the best you can do with CSS is.

```
[menID="m_John_Smith"]:hover ~ [menID="m_John_Smith"] {
    /*put the same hover style here*/
}
```

But this only highlights all siblings with same menID **after** the hovered element.

So I am sorry to tell you that CSS alone will not do the trick here, you will need to use something else.